# Meaning of ' rooted themselves ' in the following context

Tags: adjectives

Awareness beliefs rooted themselves in reason and logic.

I referred to dictionary for its meaning but did not find any suitable meaning.

Is it correct to say   Awareness beliefs fix themselves in reason and logic?

Comment: Is this sentence one that you have made up, or are you quoting a book. What book is it?  What meanings of "rooted" did you find?

Comment: this is an article

Comment: merriam websters defines this phrase ' rooted in '

Comment: What article?  Please tell us which article this comes from. Please make a link to the article if it is online. Please provide more context for the quote if you can't link to the article.

Answer (score 2):

That is almost correct. A more correct version would be:

> Awareness beliefs fix**ed** themselves in reason and logic.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rooted%20in) defines rooted as:

> formed, made, or developed by using (something) as a basis

In this case, that 'something' would be 'reason and logic'.

Answer (score 0):

The statement seems to suggest that reason and logic are the foundation (earth for a tree) of awareness beliefs.